# Initialized data member values incorrectly stored in struct

Tags: c++, class, struct

**Problematic scenario**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct sec 
{
    int a;
    char b;
};
int main()
{
    struct sec s ={25,50};
    cout << "size of struct sec: " << sizeof(s) << endl;
    cout << "a: " << s.a << " b: " << s.b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
output:
size of struct sec: 8
a: 25 b: 2
```

**Initial values for the "a = 25" and "b = 50" struct data members. however the incorrect value was saved.**

**Works for integer types.**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct sec 
{
    int a;
    char b;
};
int main()
{
    struct sec s ={25,50};
    cout << "size of struct sec: " << sizeof(s) << endl;
    cout << "a: " << s.a << " b: " << s.b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

```
output:
size of struct sec: 8
a: 25 b: 50
```

Comment: Your two code samples are identical, so they cannot produce different output. Presumably you have made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In any case `50` is the ASCII value of the character `'2'` so that explains your issue. In the first code you are printing a character. not an integer. If you want to print the integer, then try using a cast `cout << "a: " << s.a << " b: " << static_cast<int>(s.b) << endl;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing a char of value 50, which is the ascii code for '2'. Try:

```cpp
    cout << "a: " << s.a << " b: " << (int)s.b << endl;
```

Comment: C++, so prefer `static_cast<int>(s.b)` over `(int)s.b`

Comment: There's also unary plus: `+s.b`